# Валидация данных на форме с Todo List

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем нужно:

1. Не позволять добавлять дело если ничего не введено.
2. Нужно вернуть надпись "список пуст" если нет больше дел.
3. Очищать поля после добавления дел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    $(function() {
$("#addcase").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(".text").hide();

  var input = $(".input").val();

  var textarea = $(".textarea").val();

  var containerTodo =  '<div class="add-list"><div class="list-opened"><div class="title-line"><span>'+ input +'</span><button class="button"></button><button class="button-edit"></button></div><div class="add-description">'+ textarea +'</div></div></div>';

  $(".todos").append(containerTodo);
  $(".input").val(); 
});



  $('body').on('click', '.button-edit',function() {
    console.log('asd');
    //$(this).parents('.add-list').find('.add-description').slideToggle();
    var description = $(this).parents('.add-list').find('.add-description');
    let visible = description.is(':visible');
    visible ? description.slideUp() : description.slideDown();
    let rot = 'rotate(' + (visible ? 0 : 90) + 'deg)';
    $(".button-edit").css({
      '-webkit-transform': rot,
      '-moz-transform': rot,
      '-ms-transform': rot,
      '-o-transform': rot,
      'transform': rot
    });
  });


$('body').on('click', '.button',function(){
    $(this).parents(".add-list").remove();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если поля и описание пустые тогда выводить alert и просить че нить напечатать в них.
Для второго вопроса если нет блоков с таким то классом тогда присоединить надписать список пуст .
Для третьего после выполнения добавления дела/задания form.reset() делать и поля будут пустыми.